# Gitk doesn't show commit tree

Tags: gitk

When I use gitk (without any further arguments) it doesn't show any commit tree, see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dmoim.png).

Is there a way to show the commit tree?

I am using Debian jessie; git and tk are the only listed dependencies, git version is 2.1.4.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot please?  Also, what version of git are you using?

Comment: You call gitk inside your Git repository, right? Does `git log` show you what you expect?

Comment: Yes I call gitk inside the repository; `git log` shows the correct history; moreover, using the up and down arrow keys in the gitk interface makes me navigate the correct history. This was tested on multiple repositories.